# Eager-load entry field that is being paginated

Tags: entry, entries-field, eager-loading, paginate

We have this `entry` with a field called `faq` which can contain multiple `faq entries`. We paginate this field with this code:

```
{% paginate entry.faq as pageInfo, pageItems %}
```

Now Blitz Recomendations says we should `Eager-load the entry route variable.` and the example it gives is:

```
Eager-load elements of the FAQ field on the auto-injected route variable entry, for example:
{% do craft.app.elements.eagerLoadElements(className(entry), [entry], ['faq']) %}
```

So I tried:

```
{% do craft.app.elements.eagerLoadElements(className(entry), [entry], ['faq']) %}
{% paginate entry.faq as pageInfo, pageItems %}
```

which returns this error: `[web.ERROR] [TypeError] craft\helpers\Template::paginateQuery(): Argument #1 ($query) must be of type yii\db\QueryInterface, craft\elements\ElementCollection given`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When relational fields (entries, assets, etc) are eager-loaded, they either return an array of elements (Craft 3) or a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections) (Craft 4). Neither of those are possible to paginate using the `{% paginate %}` tag, which needs an [element query](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html) to work with (i.e. what relational fields return *without* eager loading).

**This means that eager-loading the `entry.faq` Entries field isn't possible in this case,** and you should ignore this particular recommendation from Blitz.

It's worth mentioning that Blitz Recommendations are just hints; all the plugin does is let you know about any element queries that aren't eager-loaded. It's up to you to evaluate each of those queries to decide if eager-loading is a) technically feasible and b) a good idea in the first place.

Towards that final point, it's important to know that **eager-loading only offers a potential performance improvement when it solves an N+1 issue (see [the official docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/dev/eager-loading-elements.html) for an example).** This means that eager-loading a *single* element's relations (like your `entry` route variable's `faq` field), isn't actually going to be more performant. In fact, in such cases eager-loading might even be a little bit *slower* due to the fact that it adds a bit of overhead (and there isn't any gain to make up for it).

Going back to the pagination: if your `faq` entries also happen to have relational fields themselves (for example, an `image` Assets field), *that* could potentially represent an N+1 issue. And if that's the case, you can still use the `{% paginate %}` tag to query for the `faq` entries *and* eager-load those entries' images to avoid the N+1; you just need to make sure that you're eager-loading the right thing, i.e. the `faq` entries' `image` field, and not the `faq` entries themselves:

```
{% paginate entry.faq.with(['image']) as pageInfo, pageItems %}

{% for faqEntry in pageItems %}
    {% set image = faqEntry.image.one() %}{# N+1 issue avoided due to the entries' image field being eager-loaded #}
{% endfor %}
```